# How to call the table value without affecting the performance

Tags: vb.net

Using VB.Net

I want to get the table value through function

Function to retrive the table value

```
Function GetFsDtValue(ByVal value As Integer) As String
        Dim conObjects As New ConnectionObjects
        conObjects.OpenConnection()

            Dim objDataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter("Select * from table1", conObjects.myConnection)
            Dim pobjDS As New DataSet("Result")
            If Not IsNothing(objDataAdapter) Then
                objDataAdapter.Fill(pobjDS)
                objDataAdapter.Dispose()
            End If
            If pobjDS.Tables.Count > 0 AndAlso pobjDS.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
                GetFsDtValue = pobjDS.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(value)
            Else
                GetFsDtValue = ""
            End If

        End Try
    End Function
```

I am calling the above function so many times like

```
txtbox1.Text = GetFsDtValue(7)
txtbox2.Text = GetFsDtValue(8)
```

Each time i am calling the function, it will open the connection again and save the tables in dataset, it will affect the performance.  Any other alternative way

like

I want to call the table values through function.  How to do it

Need vb.net code help

Comment: Is storing all information in the program an option? If so then it's better to save it all in a table (yuck) or creating a class that can represent each row which you put in a list (yay). Regardless which way you do it you can get the information from your software rather than database. = Much faster.

Comment: Oh, didn't read it properly... It's obvious you can store all the data in the software...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function in which you do this and call it FetchData or something:

```
Dim conObjects As New ConnectionObjects
        conObjects.OpenConnection()

            Dim objDataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter("Select * from table1", conObjects.myConnection)
            _pobjDS As New DataSet("Result")
            If Not IsNothing(objDataAdapter) Then
                objDataAdapter.Fill(pobjDS)
                objDataAdapter.Dispose()
            End If´
```

Let pobjDS be a global variable like this:

```
private _pobjDS as DataSet
```

In GetFsDtValue do this:

```
Function GetFsDtValue(ByVal value As Integer) As String

            If _pobjDS.Tables.Count > 0 AndAlso _pobjDS.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
                GetFsDtValue = _pobjDS.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(value)
            Else
                GetFsDtValue = ""
            End If

        End Try
    End Function
```

And voila seez fixed

Comment: Sorry. I missed one podjDS. Just Edit all of them to be _podjDS